# FFMPEG SIGSEGV error after firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault

I am trying to deploy a node project to firebase. The project uses Fluent-FFMPEG and works fine when using the firebase emulator. However, after deploying to firebase and running the function I get an error saying "ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGSEGV at ChildProcess.." Some other stackoverflow posts mentioned it could be a memory issue, so I allocated 8GB of RAM to the function and had the same error. I have no idea what could be causing this, any help would be greatly appreciated!